# Semantic-UI button loading state with tooltip

Tags: semantic-ui

Please, take a look on snippet (you need to hover over the button).

Loading works strange while button has tooltip.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h3 class="ui header">Does not work as expected</h3>
<button class="ui icon loading button" data-tooltip="tooltip"><i class="settings icon"></i></button>

<h3 class="ui header">Works because without tooltip</h3>
<button class="ui icon loading button"><i class="settings icon"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because both tooltip and loading use `:before` and `:after` styles so they will be interfering with each other.

You can fix this by wrapping your button in a `span`

```
<span data-tooltip="tooltip" data-position="right center">
  <button class="ui icon loading button">
    <i class="settings icon"></i>
  </button>
</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4uzroqjg/